# I need a specific decimal conversion I can not do that

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, linq

I would like to write the decimal value data from the database in a desired format (Format 1000145,14563 => 100.014.5,146)

You will see what I'm trying to do. I will be glad if you help me.

I have the fields to fill and fill in the pictures

```
query.ForEach(item => {
            var a= string.Format("{0:N}", item.TotalWeight);
            item.TotalWeight =Convert.ToDecimal(a);
            string.Format("{0:N}", item.TotalVolume);
            string.Format("{0:N}", item.TotalLDM);
            string.Format("{0:N}", item.TotalChargeableWeight);
            string.Format("{0:N}", item.GoodPrice);
            });
            return query;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nxMY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8gu2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your "own" numberformat with NumberFormatInfo (See: [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
using System.Globalization;

private void DecimalFormating()
{
    double input = 1000145.14563;

    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();

    //Need for grouping, so the thousendgrouping starts on the left side
    int gs = input.ToString().Split('.')[0].Length % 3;

    //First int in GroupSize[] is for the most right digits before the DecimalSeperator
    int[] GroupSizes = {gs, 3};
    nfi.NumberGroupSizes = GroupSizes;

    //Change other custom informations
    nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 3;
    nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
    nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

    string output = input.ToString("N", nfi);
}
```

NumberGroupSizes in [detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not meet my needs, thanks very much to everyone who is trying to help. I can not vote because the Score is not countable, but this is the solution that I have shared for you.

Answer (score 0):

May you use a JS library? This is a Front End solution using JS.

Try [Numeral JS](http://numeraljs.com/) for formatting and manipulating numbers.

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: project angular 4 is being used. Also DevExpress is used. If it works well, I can try it. I need to solve the problem.

Comment: @huuvan-tran Thank you in reply to your reply. I found the format for devexpress much shorter

<dxi-column dataField = "packageCount" caption = "Number of Parcels" format = ", ## 0. ####"> </ dxi-column>